# Who owns returned BSTR?

Tags: com, bstr

Suppose a method from a COM interface returns BSTR value. Am I right in my opinion that I must free it?

The code example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365382(VS.85).aspx does not do that.

Who's wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The MSDN sample is wrong.  The caller frees out and in/out bstrs.  If it's in/out you have to pass in null or a valid bstr.  If it's out only, it doesn't have to be initialized.

It's not super clear from msdn's [com allocation rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378697(VS.85).aspx), but the client stub allocates the memory on out values so from the caller's point of view the server did.  Who else can free it but the caller?

Comment: I have always found it very convenient to use `_bstr_t` instead of dealing with `BSTR` directly.

Comment: yeah, but not everyone is willing to be stuck to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 9):

Tony is correct but I wanted to expand on his answer.  The situation is not just limited to a BSTR.  The caller is responsible for freeing any memory that is returned via out or in/out parameters.